# CSS: how do I force contents in a table cell to stay on one line when browser size reduced

Tags: html, css

I have a table that has a column containing two buttons. When the browser is reduced in size, the column (i.e. the td) containing these two buttons breaks. Does anyone know how I could prevent this from happening using CSS? In other words, force the two buttons to stay next to each other?

I've tried the following and both failed:

1. putting a width in pixels on the td
2. white-space: nowrap

Here is the html:

```
<table>      
   <tr>
      <!-- several other tds before this one -->
      <td>
         <a class="sg-icon sg-i-ok"></a>
         <button class="k-button sg-grid-filter-clear-button" ng-click="clearFilterValues()">x</button>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the styling from Chrome:

[image]

[image]

Comment: image is great but we will need code (html and CSS) or even better : fiddle to be able to answer corectly.

Comment: ok thanks just updated the question with some code

Comment: give a width in pixels to the table, if you give it a percentage width it will always resize to that width and then ratio the width of the cells accordingly

Comment: Wrap the `<a>` and `button` in a `div` and give it a fixed wih

Comment: with the code you gave, it doesn't break see here : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/y75wJ/2/

Comment: @Pete - yes I think that's the issue, the table has a percentage width  and so is re-sizing each cell accordingly. Unfortunately I can't specify a width in pixels, my boss won't allow it!

Comment: @web-tiki thanks for the reply. The anchor tag has a class that references an icon which isn't available to the jsfiddle

Comment: @Tone you could add a min-width in pixels to the table so it doesn't go below the width you need for the cell to be on one line but will expand when needed

Comment: @Pete that's a good idea! The table (a kendo grid) has a width of 100% and a max-width of 100% but no min-width so will try that

Comment: ah you would have had to take the max-width % off if you had a min-width in pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `<a>` and the `<button>` in a containing `<div>` and give it a fixed width:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A5YCY/)

```
<td>
     <div class="fixed_width">
         <a class="sg-icon sg-i-ok"><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30"></a>
         <button class="k-button sg-grid-filter-clear-button" ng-click="clearFilterValues()">x</button>
     </div>
 </td>
```

---

```
.fixed_width {
    width: 80px;
}
```

Comment: @Tone I thought you said in a comment above " Unfortunately I can't specify a width in pixels, my boss won't allow it"

Answer (score 0):

I think the browser doesn't know what to do here because there's not enough space to fit everything. Logically, you'd have to either make the numbers progessively smaller or include less numbers the smaller the screensize is (or make the buttons themselves progressively smaller which is not a good option).